# How do I create an object from a JSON string using Jackson's ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have classes structured in the following way:

```
@JsonRootName("class1")
public class class1 {
    private interface1 foo;

    public interface1 getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(interface1 foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

```
@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = class2.class, name = "class2")})
public interface interface1 {
    String getType();
}
```

```
@JsonTypeName("class2")
public class class2 implements interface1 {
    private String buzz = "bar";

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "class2";
    }

    public String getBuzz() {
        return buzz;
    }

    public void setBuzz(String buzz) {
        this.buzz = buzz;
    }
}
```

If I parsed the following JSON into class1 using the `ObjectMapper` it would be fine:

```
{
    "class1": {
        "foo": {
            "class2": {
                "buzz": "not bar"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example the buzz variable in the class2 object would be set to "not bar" and the foo variable in the class1 would be set to the class2 object.

If I didn't want to modify the `buzz` variable in `class2` and just wanted the foo variable in `class1` to be set to a plain `class2` object, how would I do that? The following doesn't work since `"class2"` is interpreted as a string:

```
{
    "class1": {
        "foo": "class2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as the first example, but without the `buzz` field.

```json
{
    "class1": {
        "foo": {
            "class2": {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Woah thanks! For the sake of being more explicit in the JSON, would it be possible to pass a value like "default" to the "class2" key and then have Jackson create a plain class2 object?